# Angular 4 with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am attempting to setup a new site in Angular 4.   I want to use Firebase as a database backend.

I am using the install guide found here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md

However, when I execute `ng serve --open` I am getting this error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'OpaqueToken', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function, resolving symbol FirebaseUserConfig in
>   C:/Source/node_modules/angularfire2/tokens.d.ts, resolving symbol
>   AngularFireModule.initializeApp in
>   C:/Source/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts, resolving
>   symbol AppModule in C:/Source/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol
>   AppModule in C:/Source/src/app/app.module.ts

As I am rather a novice with Angular, I am not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/843

Comment: `npm uninstall firebase angularfire2 --save`
`npm install firebase angularfire2 --save`
seems to fixed the issue for now.   Does anyone have any ETA when AngularFire2 will officially support Angular 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try below link:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md

AngularFire2 4.0 is a refactor of the AngularFire2 package which implements @NgModule, simplifies authentication, and better supports Angular 4.